# How to add QuTip to canopy? Because I've tried many times, each time gives me an error.

Tags: python, c++

By the way this is because I would work with python to measure quantum states, and also I'd like to mention that if any of you tried or have strong ideas about it please go with explanation step by step. On the other hand, the Qutip instructions do not show any details; especially for installing on windows. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just got it working on Windows 7 64-bit in Canopy 1.4.1 64-bit by doing this:

1) Downloaded the binary package installer from Christoph Gohlke's site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#qutip. (I used `qutip‑3.0.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl`.)

2) Saved the `.whl` file to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

3) In the Canopy editor, used Tools -> Canopy Command Prompt to open a command prompt in the Canopy User Python environent.

4) Changed directory to that of step 2.

5) Entered `pip install qutip‑3.0.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl`.

6) Tested the installation in Canopy using:

```
import qutip.testing as qt
qt.run()
```

... got errors on a few tests using `str format` and `mesolve`. But mostly ok.

Where I got my info: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line.